# Кастомный Preference меняет позицию после изменения значения

Tags: android

В настройках моего приложения используется кастомный Preference - SeekBarPreference. Выглядит это так:

[alt text http://i031.radikal.ru/1312/63/051b0b9082b6.jpg](http://i031.radikal.ru/1312/63/051b0b9082b6.jpg)

Проблема заключается в том, что после каждого клика по движку (значение необязательно изменять) Control1 и Control2 меняются местами:

[image]

Происходит это в эмуляторе 2.1. В эмуляторе с 4.2.2 такая проблема не проявляется. Вопрос: из-за чего такое может происходить и в чем разница в этом плане между 2.1 и 4.2.2?

Вот код Preference:

```
public class SeekBarPreference extends Preference implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private TextView valueTextView;
    private int currentValue;
    private int max;
    private int min;
    final private String NAMESPACE="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ru.bartwell.myapp";
    private int defaultValue;

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.d("SeekBarPreference", "Init");
        max = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(NAMESPACE, "max", 99);
        min = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(NAMESPACE, "min", 0);
        defaultValue = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "defaultValue", min);
        if(defaultValue<min) defaultValue=min;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        currentValue = getPersistedInt(defaultValue)-min;
        
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.seek_bar_preference_layout, null);

        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(getTitle());
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.summary)).setText(getSummary());

        SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        bar.setMax(max-min);
        bar.setProgress(currentValue);
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        valueTextView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.value);
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentValue+min));

        return layout;
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress+min));
        valueTextView.invalidate();
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        currentValue = seekBar.getProgress();
        persistInt(currentValue+min);
        notifyChanged();
    }

}
```

Используется так (prefs.xml):

```
<ru.bartwell.myapp.SeekBarPreference
    android:key="Control1"
    android:summary="@string/control1_description"
    android:title="@string/control1"
    android:defaultValue="12"
    sbp:min="1"
    sbp:max="20" />

<ru.bartwell.myapp.SeekBarPreference
    android:key="Control2"
    android:summary="@string/control2_description"
    android:title="@string/control2"
    android:defaultValue="3"
    sbp:min="1"
    sbp:max="15" />
```

PrefActivity.java:

```
public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }

}
```

Comment: [offtop]А почему вы работаете напрямую с `SharedPreferences.Editor` вместо стандартных `persistInt()` и `getPersistedInt()`?[/offtop]

Comment: @falstaf, вы правы, исправил и обновил вопрос.

Comment: попробуй добавить каждому свой id

Comment: @Gorets, можете уточнить как именно?

Comment: android:id="seekBarPreference1", но я не уверен, у себя тоже юзал этот SeekBarPreference, но проблем таких не было

Comment: похоже что у тебя, одно id для SeekBarPreference, layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBar); - потому прыгает разметки

Comment: @Gorets, Спасибо, попробую протестировать эту версию. Ошибка проявляется только на ранних версиях андроида и только если контролов больше одного, могла остаться незамеченной.

Comment: Обнаружил, что если убрать строку с notifyChanged(), то все работает правильно, без прыжков.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 сделать 2 класса public class SeekBarPreference1  и public class SeekBarPreference2

2 layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);  / layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

3 ru.bartwell.myapp.SeekBarPreference1
    android:key="Control1"

  ru.bartwell.myapp.SeekBarPreference2
    android:key="Control1"
```

способ не торт, но попробуй